# C++ template member object

Tags: c++, templates

I'm facing a problem, a design problem. There is this template class which represent File handling/driver interface. Here is the barebone of that class.

---------------------------- FileDriver.h---------------------------

```
namespace DatabaseManager {

template<class T>
class FileDriver {

FileDriver(const char *file_name) : file_name(file_name) {}
public : 

T* fetch(size_t rec_size, long rec_num, long offset , bool write_enabled) {

// fetch data from file
}

int insert(T *rec, size_t rec_size, long rec_num, long offset) {

// insert data into file

}

inline int release(T *rec, size_t rec_size, int rec_num) {
 // close the file

}

};

}
```

Now this class is used by any class in the system which needs I/O operation. But as its a template class so i have to create objects of this class everytime i need to access a file. For example here is how a function uses this class.

```
 ---------------------- ParseSparseParticles.cpp ------------------

     #include "FileDriver.h"

     bool ParseSparseParticles::openFile() throw(ParseSparseParticlesException)
    {

       // DatabaseManager::FileMetaInfo is a struct containing meta information about a file
      DatabaseManager::FileMetaInfo *meta_info = nullptr;
      DatabaseManager::SparseParticles *particle_data = nullptr; 

      DatabaseManager::FileDriver<DatabaseManager::FileMetaInfo> meta_hndlr(meta_file_name.str().c_str());
      meta_info = meta_hndlr.fetch(sizeof(DatabaseManager::FileMetaInfo), 1, static_cast<int>(DatabaseManager::file_map_pos::START), false);

      if (meta_info) {

        DatabaseManager::FileDriver<DatabaseManager::SparseParticles> data_hndlr(file_name.str().c_str());

        particle_data = data_hndlr.fetch(sizeof(DatabaseManager::SparseParticles),
                                   meta_info->num_rec, static_cast<int>(DatabaseManager::file_map_pos::START), false);

        if (particle_data) {
          data_hndlr.release(particle_data, sizeof(DatabaseManager::SparseParticles), meta_info->num_rec);
          meta_hndlr.release(meta_info, sizeof(DatabaseManager::FileMetaInfo), 1);
          return true;
        } else {
          throw ParseSparseParticlesException("Cannot open Sparse Particles File");
        }

      } else {
        throw ParseSparseParticlesException("Cannot open Meta Info File");
      }

    }
```

So i have to like follow this exact same steps everytime i need to access any file. 
1. Open the meta info file
2. Open the actual data file
3. Close the data file
4. Close the meta file

And this gets tiresome after sometime, worse it leads to duplicate code, unstructured code, as file operation is done all over the system. So i was thinking about making an interface that will abstract the operation of I/O. And in the process of doing so i stumbled when i wanted to create FileDriver member object of the interface class, like so

```
    --------------------------- IOInterface.h ---------------------------


    #include "FileDriver.h"

    template<typename MetaFileType, typename FileType>
    class IOInterface {

    DatabaseManager::FileDriver<MetaFileType> meta_orb; // won't compile 

    DatabaseManager::FileDriver<FileType> data_orb; // won't compile

    };
```

But this won't compile as i'm including a template header into another template header. So can please anyone tell me how to solve this problem. How can i make an class that will act like an interface to FileDriver that will store the FileDriver object as long as that class object is alive.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The error i'm getting while compiling is with the IOInterface constructor.

```
IOInterface::IOInterface(std::string data_dir, std::string file_prefix, int id) :
  data_dir(data_dir),
  file_prefix(file_prefix),
  file_id(id)
{}

/var/local/PolymerizationSimulation/include/IOInterface.h:7: error: no matching function for call to 'DatabaseManager::FileDriver<DatabaseManager::MetaFileType>::FileDriver()'

/var/local/PolymerizationSimulation/include/IOInterface.h:7: error: no matching function for call to 'DatabaseManager::FileDriver<DatabaseManager::FileType>::FileDriver()'
```

Comment: What's the compilation error? There's no reason whatsoever for "including a template header into another template header" to not compile.

Comment: "including a template header into another template header". There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: *Real code* would help immensely, since (a) nothing in FileDriver is public, and (b) those objects in IOInterface both require initialization. Were FileDriver's constructor actually public, its parameter isn't optional. If you're going to strip down code, it would help if it still exhibited the problem and wasn't outright-broken due to the strip-down.

Comment: Sorry i just posted the function declaration and the basic structure as posting all of the code would really take up a lot of space (over 800 lines). Yes all of the function of FileDriver is public. The compiler is pointing at IOInterface constructor. I've updated my post to show the error.

Comment: @Maxx: You should have constructed a _minimal testcase_.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints from looking at your code:

You miss semicolons after class definition:

```
};
 ^
```

also from your example, FileDriver is not inside DatabaseManager

In this class:

```
template<class T>
    class FileDriver {
```

all members are private, even constructor, so you cannot access it. Finally this class does not provide default constructor needed by:

```
DatabaseManager::FileDriver<MetaFileType> meta_orb; // won't compile 
DatabaseManager::FileDriver<FileType> data_orb; // won't compile
```

so compiler have no idea how to create those instances, add it for FileDriver:

```
FileDriver(){}
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't put the semi colon while pasting the code. All methods of FileDriver is public and it has a public constructor, i missed out the access modifiers while posting.

Comment: @Maxx: Don't waste our time - post your _minimal testcase_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well i don't have a separate test ready as of now. Thats why i posted that function `bool ParseSparseParticles::openFile()` to explain the problem that i'm having. And the main problem is with the proper way to initialize template member object like i wanted to do in IOInterface with this expression `DatabaseManager::FileDriver<MetaFileType> meta_orb;`. But sadly it didn't compile, and as i'm quite new to template programming so i was kinda stuck with this. But anyways i will see if i can solve this somehow.

Comment: @Maxx: How did you debug the code without creating a minimal testcase?! You _did_ debug it, before posting, right..? http://sscce.org

Comment: Yes i debug just by stepping over the code line by line, as i don't yet have a testing environment or a test driven methodology ( which i'm ashamed of as i should have it already). But in this the code won't compile at all due to those two object initialization :-(